# What server-side language do I choose for cross platform application

Tags: python, cross-platform, server-side

I'm embarking on uncharted territory and am about to leave the comforts of Windows and .Net. I'm mid-savvy with Linux and am running nginx and nodejs today.

The requirements I have is to be able to develop a **server-side** implementation that can:

- run on common platforms (Linux, Win, Mac)
- indepedantly can use for instance jdbc to connect to different tsql rdbms servers (oracle, mysql, sql server, postgres)
- get me started in reasonable time (haven't been writing c/c++ in many years)
- support socket and threading
- relatively short learning curve

My questions are:

- Is python a good choise? Pros/cons
- Is python slow enough to warrant using c/c++?

Let me know if you have any questions and I'll clarify.

/K

Comment: People have successfully used Java, Python, C++ and Mono for this.  Which is better for you is a matter of personal opinion.

Comment: I like the speed which people wants to close. No comments though. It would be better if some people were more interested in asking to improve or in other ways comment to make the question comply. Personally I got the answers I was after so for me - and close are rubbish.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python would suffice. You can do web sockets, sockets and have access to almost any database under the sun.

But in my opinion, the only thing that fully does exactly what you ask for, is Java. You can use Play framework for example, that way you only use standard java, not the java enterprise.

There you have jdbc, threads, sockets and everything else, and your code will run on anything from the tiniest pc machine with windows or linux, to Solaris and even on mainframes without changing a line of code.

I personally prefer python as of late, but Play framework was very good.

You might look into Ruby on Rails if you want. Their ORM system is extremely good, and they have drivers for most relational databases and even without changing your code you can do MongoDB.

You don't really do C/C++ for web server development anymore

Comment: Thanks. A few follow up questions; From reading SO i've seen people listing java as troublesome to get running on all platforms. c/c++, only for hardcore speed freaks?

Comment: No C/C++ only if you hate yourself and don't value your time. It did matter when machines were slow, now you can even make Java execute faster than c++ code (just google it). I have never had issues with Java. Just use the SUN/Oracle version and don't try Kaffe or any other java clones unless you really know your stuff. You can easily install Play (1.2.5) on most platforms, and it includes a web server, just do "Play server" inside your directory and voila. I don't do windows at all, you can always have issues with that I guess. Just make a linux virtual machine

Comment: Hahaha!!! Roger that! I'll spawn two new machines and give both Java and Python a try and implement the same thing. Windows is unfortunately required for me or no one at work will even look at it.

Comment: You will have much easier time to install Play 1.2.5 on a windows box, it comes with tutorials and examples on the site www.playframework.com and install instructions. No need to setup apache, tornado or any other webserver to do development, and you just copy your directory straight into the linux/mac/solaris server (or whatever) and start

Comment: Python, is there an easy way there too? I normally use Komodo Edit and edit on remote server when coding for nodejs.

Comment: Django is pretty easy to install on Linux, actually quite easy. According to a quick google it should be pretty easy to install on windows as well. You can also have a look at Tornado (www.tornadoweb.org). It is asynchronous like node.js, quite cool library

Comment: Thanks! Have alot of fun work to do now!